# How to keep the style of the support library's checkbox on a customized checkbox view?

Tags: android, checkbox, android-support-library, android-styles

### Background

I use the support library's "Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" theme for my app.

### The problem

Thing is , I use a customized Checkbox (a class that extend "CheckBox") , and for some reason I don't get the same style of it as the native one, even though its code shouldn't change anything, and even though the UI designer shows it's ok.

Here's a screenshot showing that situation.

UI designer:

[image]

Android Kitkat device:
[image]

And here's the XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Native Checbox"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Native Checbox checked"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"/>

    <lb.test.CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Customized Checbox"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"/>

    <lb.test.CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Customized Checbox checked"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I prefer the normal style that's used for the native checkbox.

for the simplicity, I've made this test as minimal as possible, and you can just put CTORs for the customized checkbox, making it nearly identical to the normal checkbox.

### The question

How should I overcome this weird behavior? Why can't the UI designer show the true way it will be shown for such a simple case?

Are there other views that I should know about, which have this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [AppCompat v21 blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) on widget tinting:

> When running on devices with Android 5.0, all of the widgets are tinted using the color theme attributes we just talked about. There are two main features which allow this on Lollipop: drawable tinting, and referencing theme attributes (of the form ?attr/foo) in drawables.
>
> AppCompat provides similar behaviour on earlier versions of Android for a subset of UI widgets:
>
> Everything provided by AppCompat’s toolbar (action modes, etc)
>
> - EditText
> - Spinner
> - CheckBox
> - RadioButton
> - Switch (use the new [android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SwitchCompat.html))
> - CheckedTextView

Unfortunately, one limitation of this is that it is done only when you use those exactly classes in your XML files - not subclasses. such as your `lb.test.CheckBox`. There is a note in the FAQ on that post that states "This may change in the future.", but nothing has been released as of yet.

Comment: So how can I solve this? I really need this customized view ... There must be a style or something that they use for pre-Lollipop... Otherwise I wouldn't have seen it this way on Kitkat...

Comment: Per that same FAQ: "The widget tinting in AppCompat works by intercepting any layout inflation and inserting a special tint-aware version of the widget in its place...The special tint-aware widgets are currently hidden as they’re an unfinished implementation detail" so you'd have to reverse engineer what their tint aware widget is doing if you want the same behavior on your custom view.

Comment: This is really weird. I was sure I'd find it somewhere in the drawable or the code. Even the theme itself is very minimal : it has values for "windowActionBar" and "android:windowNoTitle", and that's it. It doesn't even show it has a parent... Do you know of a library that has those styles? Maybe this would be the solution for now.

Comment: In the AppCompat exploded AAR, I do see a `abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_000.png` and `abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_015.png` which look like the untinted version of the drawables used.